# Angular JS image array coding trouble

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I can't get the images to display, it's supposed to display a thumbnail and full image for each "gem" the angular tutorial isn't detailed enough..

heres my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
   <h3>
    {{product.name}}
    <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
    <img ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
   </h3>
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS CODE:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store', []);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
    this.products  = gems;
});

var gems = [
{
    name: "dodecahedron",
    price: 2.95,
    description: ". . .",
    images: [
    {
        full: 'gemfull.gif',
        thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'
},
{
        full: 'gemfull.gif',
        thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'

},

],
    name: "Pentagonal Gem",
    price: 5.95,
    description: ". . .",
    images: [
    {
        full: 'gemfull.gif',
        thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'

        full: 'gemfull.gif',
        thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'

},
],
]
})();
```

How can i get this to work?

It's supposed to be like a shop, but i can't seem to get the JS (or html) to work proper instead i just get `"{{product.name}} {{product.price | currency}}"` in the browser when i run the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var gems = [` variable is not proper formated.

I have fix `var gems` variable and your code is working fine. **Closing braces `[`, `{` are not at proper places.**

Check below snippet without images:

```js
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('store', []);

    var gems = [{
        name: "dodecahedron",
        price: 2.95,
        description: ". . .",
        images: [
        {
            full: 'gemfull.gif',
            thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'
        },
        {
            full: 'gemfull.gif',
            thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'

        },

        ]},{
            name: "Pentagonal Gem",
            price: 5.95,
            description: ". . .",
            images: [
            {
                full: 'gemfull.gif',
                thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'
            },{
                full: 'gemfull.gif',
                thumb: 'gemthumb.gif'

            },
            ],
        }
        ];

        app.controller('StoreController', function(){
            this.products  = gems;
        });

    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
</head>
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
   <h3>
    {{product.name}}
    <em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}</em>
    <img ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
  </h3>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```